# Visual Studio 2010 add service reference Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, ssl, client-certificates

I want to add a service reference to my visual studio project.
When doing this I get the following error:

> There was an error downloading 'xxxxxxxx/yyyyyy?wsdl'. The request was
>   aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved: 'xxxxxxxx/yyyyyy?wsdl'. Could not
>   establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'xxxxxxxx'. The
>   request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. If the
>   service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution
>   and adding the service reference again.

The remote service(not mine)requires a client certificate, which I own and have installed on my local machine under the LOCAL_COMPUTER and CURRENT_USER
the certificate was installed correctly, I can access the service in browser.

Is there a way of telling Visual Studio to take a client certificate somehow? Or maybe to I need to contact the other end to change some config stuff on their side?

thanks

Comment: Visual studio should show a window with certificate selection that are acceptable to the server. It should be similar to what browser does when you access the wsdl from browser. Try to restart VS. Make sure you run VS under the same account as you run browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the wsdl file included another wsdl file. Visual Studio couldn't handle that. I tried getting the include reference in a browser and saved it locally. Then I changed the reference in the first wsdl to the local wsdl that I downloaded in browser.

So, best thing to do is:

- save wsdl locally
- check includes in the wsdl, save these locally also, and reference the local versions.

Answer (score 3):

You could request the WSDL manually and then create the proxy using svcutil. This should end up with the same result.